# How Can I get a realistic Industrial Plastic Material - Bump With Shiny Graining

Tags: materials, node-editor

My Goal is to achieve this texture:

With a noise texture -> Bump -> normal I already get the rough plastic feel.

My Question is, how to get the Bumps to reflect?

[image]

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Invert the bump mask and use it for roughness

Comment: Sure would be nice to see what you already have. There are many tutorials on how to make procedural plastic materials. This could be made with a noise texture plugged into a bump map into a color ramp and tweaking some specular values. You could even plug the noise into the specular socket.

Comment: Is the picture you show your own texture or is it a reference image?

Comment: the picture in my question is my reference image. 
currently im noodeling around with those nodes, but that final bit of reflecting is still missing, kinda stuck 
maybe you guys have an idea. highy appreciate your help.

https://imgur.com/a/Zlm1kkz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you say you can use a *Noise* as Bump, also use the eyedropper to catch the blue color, reduce the *Roughness* and increase the *Specular* values of the *Principled BSDF*. After that, of course, you need some lights and environment to reflect:

[image]

Comment: thank you this helped a lot! Ill play around with those settings